# Applying nested "where" to two other where bindings

Tags: haskell

I want to do something like this:

```
foo x = a + b
    where
        a = bar z
        b = baz z
            where
                z = qux x
```

But that's not valid Haskell; `z = qux x` applies to `b = baz z`, but not to `a = bar z`.

What can I do instead?

Comment: What's wrong with putting `z = qux x` in the outer `where` block?

Comment: Didn't realize that worked! Thank you. Now that I think of it, it seems obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right-hand sides of `where`-bindings can refer to variables defined in the same block:

```
foo x = a + b
    where
        a = bar z
        b = baz z
        z = qux x
```

works fine.

Comment: Didn't realize that worked! Thank you. Now that I think of it, it seems obvious.